# Tag synonym request: vert.x

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, synonym-request

I noticed that there are (afaik) 4 tags regarding [Vert.x](http://vertx.io). The official name is **Vert.x**.

[vertx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertx), [vert.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vert.x), and [vertx.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertx.io)

I suggest to merge these three tags or mark [vertx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertx) and [vertx.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertx.io) as synonyms of [vert.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vert.x).

Also there is a version specific tag called [vertx3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertx3). So this should be a just a synonym of [vert.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vert.x).